# I get the SAME output for the md5 hash, but the base64_encode result is not the same

Tags: php, encryption, base64, md5, encode

I am trying to connect my site to a payment site that requires a certain validation key that is first md5 hashed, then base64 encoded. So the instructions pdf gave an example given a certain input string:

```
input EX123123456100.00
md5(input) => 231cd7f8e0151f6e0c4a60b33752a1e7
base64_encode(md5(input)) => IxzX+0AVH24MSmCzN1Kh5w==
```

So when I try this sample input, I get the **SAME** output for the `md5` hash. But the `base64_encode` result is not the same. The instructions says that the `base64_encode` needs to encode a value in hex format for this to work. And I guess my `base64_encode` in my php script is encoding a string which is why I am getting a different result from the pdf file. So how do I make the `base64_encode` encode a hex value? Or is there another reason I am getting a different value?

Comment: MD5 is not guaranteed to be unique.  But base64 is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey well out `md5` results are the same so if you pass the SAME input into base64 then we should get the same result again right?

Comment: If you're getting a different result for the base64 output, it means that you passed in a different input.

Comment: @RobertHarvey well the input from the example and mine are the **EXACT** same, so are the md5, but it's the base64 that differs. I am so lost as to why that could be

Comment: You're missing something.  Looking at the code above, I'd say that you believe that your MD5 is the same, but it actually is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make a lot of sense to base64 encode something that is already a perfectly good ASCII string. If you pass a `true` as the second parameter to `md5`, it will return the raw binary data instead of a hex string. Base64 encoding *that* gives you the proper example value:

```
base64_encode(md5($key, true))
```

Either you have misunderstood the instructions, or the instructions are misleading.